# Missing ldd shows "not found" "libgcc_so.s.1" but ldconfig shows it is installed running lmstat

Tags: docker, debian, libgcc

I am trying to run the "lmstat" application inside a debian:bookworm docker container. Executing the ldd command on it shows a missing library:

```
root@ce6a20e3afbc:/lib32# ldd / 
   opt/cad/cadence/IC616/tools/bin/lmstat
   linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f54000)
   libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7f47000)
   libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf7e42000)
   libgcc_s.so.1 => not found
   libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf7c1a000)
   libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf7c15000)
   /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f56000)
```

But running ldconfig on the library shows it is installed:

```
root@ce6a20e3afbc:/lib32# ldconfig -p | grep libgcc
    libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Since it looked like it was pulling all dependencies from lib32, I suspected I needed to install a i386 version of libgcc-s1. I tried to download and forcibly install it, but I got this scary message:

```
root@ce6a20e3afbc:/lib32# apt install ./libgcc-s1_13.1.0-6_i386.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgcc-s1:i386' instead of './libgcc-s1_13.1.0-6_i386.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libgcc-s1 : Breaks: libgcc-s1:i386 (!= 12.2.0-14) but 13.1.0-6 is to be installed
     libgcc-s1:i386 : Depends: gcc-13-base:i386 (= 13.1.0-6) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.35) but it is not installable
                      Breaks: libgcc-s1 (!= 13.1.0-6) but 12.2.0-14 is to be installed
    E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Any ideas on how to make this one lib get installed?

Comment: The first and last complaint both seem to be that you can't have the i386 and x86_64 versions of this library installed at the same time.  Since a Docker image usually only includes a single application, though, this shouldn't be a problem.  Can you change your Dockerfile's `RUN apt-get install` line to install `libgcc-s1:i386` instead of just `libgcc-s1`?